# Flutter project fails to build when gradle gets upgraded. Error: Type 'FlutterTask' property 'assets' is missing an input or output annotation

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

When I try to build my application on a usb device, the build crashes displaying this log output

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' (type 'FlutterTask').
>
>   - Type 'FlutterTask' property 'assets' is missing an input or output annotation.
>
>     Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.
>
>     Possible solutions:
>
>     1. Add an input or output annotation.
>     2. Mark it as @Internal.
>
>     Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation
>     for more details about this problem.
>   - Type 'FlutterTask' property 'assetsDirectory' is missing an input or output annotation.
>
>     Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.
>
>     Possible solutions:
>
>     1. Add an input or output annotation.
>     2. Mark it as @Internal.
>
>     Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation
>     for more details about this problem.
>   - Type 'FlutterTask' property 'buildMode' is missing an input or output annotation.
>
>     Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.
>
>     Possible solutions:
>
>     1. Add an input or output annotation.
>     2. Mark it as @Internal.
>
>     Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation
>     for more details about this problem.
>   - Type 'FlutterTask' property 'fastStart' doesn't have a configured value.
>
>     Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.
>
>     Possible solutions:
>
>     1. Assign a value to 'fastStart'.
>     2. Mark property 'fastStart' as optional.
>
>     Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#value_not_set
>     for more details about this problem.
>   - Type 'FlutterTask' property 'flutterExecutable' is missing an input or output annotation.
>
>     Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.
>
>     Possible solutions:
>
>     1. Add an input or output annotation.
>     2. Mark it as @Internal.
>
>     Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation
>     for more details about this problem.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1

Please help to find a solution to this problem

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is happening because you updated gradle in your project to gradle 7. And gradle 7 has some new annotation property which must be reviewed.

I also faced this and filed an issue on github.
[This is the link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79155#issuecomment-812817965)

So the choice you have

1. Downgrade your gradle( < 7 )
2. Make changes as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/79167/files) PR.

In the referred page(Pull Req) . There is a section named `Files Changed`. See the green colored lines over there. Just edit your `gradle` file and add/edit same as green colored lines.

Comment: Go to `android->gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties` in the last line change `7.0-all` to `6.7-all` or whatever you want

Comment: `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.8.3` will roll back to the last 6.x version released

Comment: it is a temporary solution, we can't use old version for ever, how we can solve this problem with gradle >= 7

Comment: @MohammadHadi It's(2nd solution) not a temporary solution. Please care to read my answer CAREFULLY. I have referred a PR which solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the PR, miroring it worked perfectly!

Comment: @ProblematicDude Kindly make your answer more descriptive. What exactly do you mean by make changes as per the PR? Which file to change?

Comment: @JoelGMathew Sure

Comment: Update android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties >>>> `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip`
and android/build.gradle >>> `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.0'`

Comment: CORRECTION: it's >>>> `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'`

Comment: upgrade classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'  to  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
and I receive this error:
Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to *
then add this to your gradle.properties
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M \
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED