# Specific errors when running Flutter Build

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, mobile, flutter-plugin

I need someone with experience in Flutter/mobile to help me, since after a long look at documentation and StackOverflow and a few days of trying, I was unable to resolve the errors:

Repository: https://github.com/gabe-santana/ReachUp

Path of the project to be built: src/MobileApp

Command that fails:
`flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64`

With Gradle between 7 and 7.2, the following type of error occurs:

```
In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'assets' is missing an input or output annotation.

Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.
                                                                    
Possible solutions:
  1. Add an input or output annotation.
  2. Mark it as @Internal.
```

References used in resolution attempts:
[Flutter project fails to build when gradle gets upgraded. Error: Type 'FlutterTask' property 'assets' is missing an input or output annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137816/flutter-project-fails-to-build-when-gradle-gets-upgraded-error-type-flutterta)

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/79167/files

The difficulty here is locating the files for this "FlutterPlugin" plugin, to make the changes indicated in the second link. Using Android Studio or looking in the files, I was unable to locate this plugin.

Upgrading to version 7.3, the following error occurs:

```
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\guilh\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\ReachUp\src\MobileApp\android\settings.gradle' (
```

C:\Users\guilh.gradle\caches\7.3\scripts\57mic8ee9c80a5aohp3jxpiw6).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 65

Reference used in resolution attempts:
[Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240279/could-not-open-settings-generic-class-cache-for-settings-file)

When using version 7.4 or later:
[No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114728/no-matching-variant-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle7-4-0-was-found)

I've tried several things, different Java/Gradle version configurations, but these errors keep occurring. I would really appreciate anyone who can show me a path, or even open a PR correcting it. The project is the demo of my startup ReachUp.

Comment: Some detail as to how you upgraded the github project to Flutter 2.10 may be useful. I still see an older version of Kotlin in the Android gradle file: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'` , ref: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes#released-in-flutter-210 and https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/kotlin-version but I don't know if it is meaningful.